# Finding component's x,y location

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, adobe, mxml

I have a component that changes its location based on other elements. I'm trying to find its x and y position at different intervals, so I tried `compname.x` and `compname.y`.

The `x` position seems to be working, but the `y` position is always 0. I'm guessing I need to play with `localToGlobal` or `contentToGlobal` or one of those conversions. Is that the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A component's x and y values are relative to it's parent.  Flex calls this the content coordinate system; and the contentToGlobal should give you the answers you need.

Read up on positioning components, which explains the content, local, and viewable coordinates:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=size_position_2.html

And read up on the Flex coordinate system:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=containers_intro_5.html#254752

If you had a working example it may be easier to give a specific answer.

Answer (score 2):

...also, have a look at *getBounds()* - this method returns you the position relative to other display objects.

simon